# How to additional control to ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am building out an `ItemsControl` that holds `Grid` elements. Each time an item is added to an `ObservableCollection`, a new `Grid` control is created in the `ItemsControl`. Right now I have some margin between each Grid control but I want to have a `TextBox` between each control but I am unable to add it appropriately.

If my Grids look like this in the item control

```
----------------

----------------

   I would want the text box here.

----------------

----------------

  And here

----------------

----------------
```

As of now, this is my `ItemsControl`:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
                    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentsInClassCollection}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Grid.Row="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="5, 0, 15, 50" Height="70">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{Binding StudentMemberColor}">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <dxe:TextEdit Grid.Column="1" Margin="5, 5, 5, 5" Width="50"  Height="50" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                                              FontFamily="Helvetica" FontWeight="Thin" FontSize="16"
                                                              Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: That TextBlock should be part of your ItemTemplate.

Comment: How would I position it directly under each Grid and directly above the subsequence Grid?

Comment: By putting it at the top of the elements in the DataTemplate. Then don't show the first one by binding its Visibility to an appropriate item property. Or something similar.

Comment: I can't directly put a TextBox on top of the DataTemplate, under the ItemsControl.Template.

Comment: Inside the Grid in the DataTemplate of course. Add RowDefinitions, or another, "outer" Grid.